# How do I get a 1960s film look, like technicolor?

Tags: video, editing, camera, dslr

What modern digital camera,video editing software and lense, can offer the same look/color/grain of 1960s movies, like james bond thunderball etc. Lighting systems to if possible, also if any can name which old cameras and lenses they used back then too, would also be helpful.

Comment: Why not get a modern 16mm camera or 35mm camera and use color film in it? A lot of people do that still. Everything is modern in the process

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much any professional grade video editing software will have "color Correction/Color grading" capabilities -- this is the part of the art that you are looking for. Obviously, the "grain" you'll get here is digital/simulated noise, and not actual particles of chemicals. this is the Instagram filter before there was Instagram.

the website "shotonwhat?" is a good resource to see which actual cameras (and lenses, but not always) were used for movies. Lenses, lighting, makeup and wardrobe and production design also make a big impact on the look of the film, some of which you've mentioned.

Another big part of the equation is the "film stock" -- the actual film used in 35mm/16mm/8mm cameras -- which had countless varieties based on different factors. Individual film stocks often had special characteristics (sometimes intended, sometimes not) which were favored by cinematographers/directors.

the digital equivalent of a film stock is called a LUT (a look up table). so the way it works is this : you shoot the scene in the digital camera's "flat" mode to get the most information on your chip. Then you apply the LUT to make it look like how you want to. On set, you can live preview your LUT to approximate how it's going to look like in post, unless you're just playing with it in post from scratch.

It's hard to give a specific answer to your question without spraying a bunch of brand names -- which is frowned upon here -- but I hope my answer helps you in farther research.

Answer (score 1):

A camera that can shoot in raw will have the ability to do so. Also you need full frame or even medium format for the depth of field and of course the higher quality per pixel.

- Raw shooting = a must
- Full frame = minimum must
- Medium Format = best option (but may be too expensive)

Large format video cameras do not exist, only photo cameras

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is Any and All really as technology has improved you can achieve all of this, but what you need is really HOW to achieve this, and this comes down to the team you are working with (normally with many many years of experience).

Now days you still need all of this but a lot of it can be done in Post using a really good colorist. but this question is way to broad for this forum, I would suggest getting onto a film making course and watching a lot of Behind the Scenes if you can

Answer (score 0):

An amateur response to this will be to tell you to buy {insert plugin name here}, however the real answer is much deeper than this, and would be best answered by talking to a real-world cinematographer. I recommend you get in touch with your local chapter of ACS or BCS and talk to a local cinematographer. All the movies back in the days will have been shot on film, so yes - lenses, lighting and film stock will have had a big effect in generating the look.